# Is there a way to have two Package Manager Consoles open in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, terminal, package-manager-console

Similar to how you can have several tabs open in the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Package Manager Console is not considered a full feature terminal, but something specific to NuGet, and I guess that's why the designers think that only one of that is enough. If you really look for a terminal, use other extensions, https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AProperTerminalForVisualStudio.aspx

Comment: @LexLi great thanks!

Comment: Just open a new desktop PowerShell window with the NuGet PowerShell module loaded, I guess.